# Unable to start YARN - Error starting JobHistoryServer

Tags: cloudera, hadoop-yarn

I am having issues while restarting YARN service. It keeps failing with errors shown in the logs below. YARN was working fine until last week and then the below error messages started to pop up all of a sudden.

Tried restarting YARN/JOB history server. Nothing worked. Kindly help to alleviate this issue.

Thanks,
Vinoth

```
Error starting JobHistoryServer
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class    org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobACLsManager from class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HistoryFileManager
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HistoryFileManager.serviceInit(HistoryFileManager.java:503)
at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory.serviceInit(JobHistory.java:94)
at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceInit(CompositeService.java:107)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistoryServer.serviceInit(JobHistoryServer.java:145)
at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistoryServer.launchJobHistoryServer(JobHistoryServer.java:222)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistoryServer.main(JobHistoryServer.java:232)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you working in a pseudo environment?
Also not clear what command you are using to restart.
You can try the below command to restart :
sudo service hadoop-master stop
sudo service hadoop-master start

-Senthil

Comment: It's a 4 node cluster. I believe some configuration has been messed up here despite several attempts to restart the job history server .